# Background Color Changes with Every Click

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I cannot explain this. When my scene first renders, the background color is set to a light gray color - just as I intend it. But as soon as I click on any clickable object (button or stepper), the background color changes to a dark red color. Then, I click again (on the same object or any other), and the screen goes back to its original color. This gray-red-gray-red toggling goes on forever.

I did not intend for this to happen, and I have no idea why it is happening. Since this is an OpenGL app, there are lots of color changes that occur as various objects are drawn and rendered. But isn't the background color controlled only by `glClearColor`? There are way too many lines in my code to post here, and I wouldn't expect anyone to look at them, so I'll just post the drawInRect method. This is the only place that I ever call `glClearColor`.

I'm still very new to iOS and to OpenGL ES 2.0, so I guess I'm asking for advice. What other ways other then `glClearColor` is it possible to use to change the background color of the screen? Clearly there is some line of code in here that is doing this, but I have no idea what it would be. I have no references to a dark red color anywhere, so I'm stumped. Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self drawUpperLeftScene];
    [self drawUpperRightScene];
}
```

EDIT: I've traced this to the `glScissor` / `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` combination. If I comment these lines out, my color switching problem goes away. But that blows up my whole app, so I'd rather live with the color problem. Anyone know why this happens and what I can do to correct it?

```
glViewport(0, FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH/2, FRAME_HEIGHT/2);
glScissor(0, FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH/2, FRAME_HEIGHT/2);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

Comment: Thanks. I read that post right before I made this one. As far as I can tell, it only mentions changing the background color with glClearColor. It does some things with slowly changing that color, but  always with glClearColor, very similar to what I am doing (or trying to do).